# Get the status of a live stream for a VideoDisplay control

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, adobe

I'm looking for a way to find the status of a live stream through a VideoDisplay (or any other method really). I am interested to know if the stream is currently being published to or if the publisher has stopped. This is for a Flex/Flash ActionScript 3 project.

Is there a way to do this or is this ANOTHER oversight by adobe?

flex flash adobe adobe-flex actionscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only found one solution, and that's using the NetStream object in combination with a video control.

The video control must be manually added to an

```
nsListen = new NetStream(nc);
nsListen.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, nsListenHandler);
nsListen.play(streamname);

var v:Video = new Video();
v.attachStream(nsListen);
uicontrol.add(v);
```

Finally, the event status is returned in nsListenHandler:

```
private function nsListenHandler(e:Event):void
{
    if(e is NetStatusEvent)
    {
        var nse:NetStatusEvent = NetStatusEvent(e);
        if(nse.info.code == "NetStream.Play.Failed")
        {
            // Big error.

        }
        if(nse.info.code == "NetStream.Play.PublishNotify")
        {
            // Stream has just been published

        }
        if(nse.info.code == "NetStream.Play.UnpublishNotify")
        {
            // Stream has just been unpublished

        }
        trace(NetStatusEvent(e).info.code);
        trace(NetStatusEvent(e).info.description);
    }
}
```

Only this code wont do is tell you if a stream is already successfully being published to.

Answer (score 0):

You can dig into NetStatusEvent events.

Check this [live docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html)